# Need to set pop up at top instead of inposition centre

Tags: ios

I just followed one project for use pop up.But in that project the pop up view position is in centre.But i need to show pop up at top (i.e should show up in top with use half space of navigation bar)[github project](https://github.com/evnaz/ENPopUp)

I use `UIViewController+ENPopUp.m` `UIViewController+ENPopUp.h` `JWBlurView.h` `JWBlurView.m` files.I have changed all values .But not able to show pop up at top.i need to show pop up at this image position

But in that project the position is in centre. Knindly any one can help me out.I need show pop up at top [Like this image](https://www.dropbox.com/s/edsxy7cbs5mna02/Help%20Modal.png?dl=0)

Thanks in advance !

Comment: @Cristiano Alves    can you help me out

Comment: why devoting my question.Instead of devoting .Can you plz explain me why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is not clear.I assume that you want to show pop at top of your viewcontroller instead of that project popup showing at centre.If so, then this is your solution:

I will explain with that `github project` that you post in your question.
you can change what ever you want in your own project. Go to  `ENViewController.m`.And change the code to

```
- (IBAction)showPopUp:(id)sender
{
    UIViewController *vc = [[UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main_iPhone" bundle:nil] instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"PopUp"];
    vc.view.frame = CGRectMake(20, 30, 270.0f, 230.0f);
    [self presentPopUpViewController:vc];
}
```

You can also change your popup viewcontroller size and update that size,height in this line on your `showpopup action method:`

```
vc.view.frame = CGRectMake(20, 30, Any size, Any height);
```

And if you want to change your postion of pop up view means .you can use any X , Y Values in this line on your `showpopup action method:`

```
vc.view.frame = CGRectMake(x, Y, Any size, Any height);
```

Then go to `UIViewController+ENPopUp.m` On under //Customize popUpView.delete one line(i have comment that).

```
// Customize popUpView
popUpView.layer.cornerRadius = 8.0f;
popUpView.layer.masksToBounds = YES;
popUpView.layer.zPosition = 99;
popUpView.tag = kENPopUpViewTag;
//popUpView.center = overlayView.center;
[popUpView setNeedsLayout];
[popUpView setNeedsDisplay];

[overlayView addSubview:popUpView];
[sourceView addSubview:overlayView];
```

Hope this helpfull.If not please ask your question clear .Let me know !

Comment: Yes i need to show my pop up view at top.thanks for your answer.will check

Comment: Actually my viewcontroller(my pop up view) is 270 X 400.If i change my value can i able to show pop up

Comment: see there is nothing about what (x,y) yu have.yu can change any width and height in that `Show popup method`

Comment: @ sathish chinniah ok will check out